Why the architeture of Resnet18 is suitable to images classification?
I am studying convolutional networks and in particular I have focused on the ResNet18 network.  I've been studying ResNet18 and understand the purpose of skip connections and residual network. However, I'm still unclear on why the specific structures of Basic Blocks and Bottleneck Blocks are particularly well-suited for image classification tasks. Can any of you help me?

everything is nicely explained in the original paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385
